# Python iterrows() to index and drop rows from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm iterating over a df and want to drop rows based on a condition. It's like to check the contents of a sting for a character and drop if it does not exist. I have tried the code below, with exceptions. How can I access the third column's iterative row value and check for contains.

```
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    if not row[2].contains(','):
        df_new.drop(index, inplace = True)
```

An exception is thrown:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

I've tried a variety of string assignment also like:

```
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    string = str(row[2])
    if not string.contains(','):
        df_new.drop(index, inplace = True)
```

Comment: You can use `‘,’ in str(row[2])` for checking.

Comment: `df_new = df_new[df_new[~column_name].str.contains(',')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [in](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator:

```
for index, row in df_new.iterrows():
    if ',' not in str(row[2]):
        df_new.drop(index, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did what I was intending

Answer (score 3):

Might be quicker to do.

```
df_new = df_new[~df_new.Column_name.str.contains(",")]
```

Comment: _Might_ is important because the `.str` accessor methods are wrappers over standard Python methods.

Comment: Use `regex=False` for a performance boost. But, yes, this isn't necessarily faster than a list comprehension, i.e. `df_new[[',' not in val for val in df_new['col']]]`.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance but I find it easier to understand.

Comment: The method from chitown88 is easier for me to understand. I'm not very familiar with list comprehensions yet. Testing the solution now tho, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: chitown88's method actually did not leave me with the correct solution though. I was left with only 9 rows of data, when there should be ~200 left that contain the string `,`

Comment: I’m sure there’s people that could say why exactly it’s only returning 9 instead of 200. But for me, I wouldn’t be able to tell you without seeing exactly what’s in that column causing that.